# Display custom fields created with RightPress WooCommerce Custom Fields plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I am trying to output values that I have created using [WooCommerce Custom Fields](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields/11332742) *from RightPress*. Now I have created custom product properties and I want these fields and its product specific values to be show in woo-commerce product widget.

But am not familiar with WooCommerce and custom fields functions. Could some body help me out to get my desired output.

I just altered only html part of the product widget template and d'ont know how to call the php functions.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product widget entries.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php.
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.5
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    return;
}

?>
<li>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_start', $args ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ); ?>">
        <?php echo $product->get_image(); // PHPCS:Ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
        <br/><span class="product-title"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product->get_name() ); ?></span>
    </a>
    <div class="product_field"><ul class="product_property">
    <li>Filter Type: <?php wccf_print_product_prop_values(array( 'item_id' => '115')); ?></li>
    <li>Special Size Available:</li>
    <li>Filter Class / Grade:</li>
    <li>Media Type:</li>
    <li>Gasket:</li>
    <li>Frame Material:</li>
    <li>Filter Depth:</li>
    </ui>
    </div>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() ); // PHPCS:Ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); // PHPCS:Ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_end', $args ); ?>
</li>
```

Here in [this link](https://swadesfilter.com/) under our "Product Section" on our website, I have some product properties below the product image. 
Like for example: Filter Type, Class and so I need the widget to output those data which I already entered in the back end.

Some related link about the plugin: [How to display field or field value on custom pages?](https://support.rightpress.net/hc/en-us/articles/115000163123-How-to-display-field-or-field-value-on-custom-pages-)

I only need to print the `product_property_values`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because WooCommerce Custom Fields plugin (from RightPress) is an unofficial commercial third party plugin used by very few people and this question should be asked in [the author's support threads](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields/11332742/support) instead.

Comment: Mostly nobody can answer this question here as developers mostly doesn't use this plugin.